# Commutator and upper-lower centers question

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a normal group of a group $G$. $H$ is a subgroup of the $k$-th lower center $\gamma_k(G)$.
I have a relation like the following
$$
[H,G,G,\dots, G] = 1 \qquad (n\; \text{times} \; G)
$$
but I don't know why this implies that $H \leq \mathrm{Z}_n(G)$, where $\mathrm{Z}_n(G)$ denotes the $n$-th upper center. Any idea? The group is not assumed to be nilpotent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming $[H,G,G,\ldots, G]=[\ldots[[H,G],G],\ldots, G]$ here.

We prove this by induction. Clearly if $[H]=H=1$, $H\le Z_0(G)=1$. Now suppose $[H,G]\le Z_k(G)$. Then if $\phi$ is the canonical projection, $G\to G/Z_k(G)$, $\phi([H,G])=1$, or $[\phi(H),\phi(G)]=1$. Therefore $\phi(H)\le Z(\phi(G))$. Then since $Z_{k+1}(G)=\phi^{-1}(Z(\phi(G))$ (since it is the unique normal subgroup of $G$ such that $\phi(Z_{k+1}(G))=Z(G/Z_k(G))$, and since $\phi(H)\le Z(\phi(G))$, this gives $H\le Z_{k+1}(G)$.

We are now done by induction, although this may be slightly unclear still.

As an example, if we have $[H,G,\ldots,G]\le Z_0(G)$, $n$ times $G$, then $[H,G,\ldots,G] \le Z_1(G)$, $n-1$ times $G$, and in general $[H,G,\ldots,G] \le Z_k(G)$, $n-k$ times $G$, and when $k=n$, we have $H\le Z_n(G)$ as desired.

It's been a bit since I've done group theory, so you may want to check this, but it seems ok, and you don't seem to need any conditions on $H$ either.

Comment: It seems that $[H,G] \leq Z_k(G)$ is suitable with the case n=2, however your argument is fundamentally correct.

Comment: @k662398 if my assumption about the meaning of your notation is correct, I think you'll find that my argument is a valid induction that will show the claim for all $n$. If your notation means something different, then I'm not sure what to do, but I'm glad it was helpful.